# Upper bound of $nc^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is it true that $nc^n \leq (c+1)^n$, where $c$ is a constant? If so, how?

Comment: Try induction to prove your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from $$\left(\frac{c}{c+1}\right)^n\cdot n \to 0$$
when $n\to \infty$.